# Shopify snippet data transformations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid, dataflow

Is it possible to get global object data, eg.: `collections`, find products which I want to map/filter/whatever and the result render as the liquid template again and inject to the snippet code? I can get collection data by `var collections = '{{collections | json}}'` and transform this, but I have have no idea how to put transformed data into forloop in my snippet template? Is it possible to rerender snippet template or inject data to already exist empty forloop and update view?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to rerender liquid files once it's done. In order to change dynamicly content, and separate templates to components you have to use handlebars.js. It works ok.